# PHP set daily number in range for each ID

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to calculate a sort or "daily random number" in a range, which can't be guessed, for each user in our site but can't figure out how to do it.

I don't want a random number either, it must be a calculated number in PHP, not an additional database field or anything similar.

I thought at a function who can take the user's ID and the day of year and calculate this number.

Example:
USERID: 12345, Range: 0-7 (constant values for every user)
DayOfYear: 250 (change every day)

Then something like: ((12345 + 250) MODULO 8) (so I've range from 0 to 7 for each user). The problem is that the same number will come out every 8 days in a loop that user will find very fast.

Each user doesn't necessarily need a different number for every day, even the same number would be OK for a few days, but not all users must have the same number. Also, most important, no loop scenario, so user can't guess their daily number.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why? What is the purpose?

Comment: This is for a little game, customer can guess a number every day and can access a special page if he does. but since it's a short time contest, I didn't want to manage this on a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many answers to this question and none would be the best ... but I'm in a funny mood:

```
$id = hexdec(substr(md5($userId . date('z')), 0, 3)) % 8;
```

Use the md5-function to get a hex-string from a string. Then use a part of this string to calculate the mod 8.

For the next 10 days the id will be 5,7,5,3,6,0,2,0,2,4 when using your user id

**But to guess a number between 0 and 7 isn't so hard, don't uses this for security ...**